# Three.js: OrbitControl with zoom damping?

Tags: javascript, three.js

The damping feature has been added in the r.72dev branch of three.js.
It works great for smoother rotating.

Does it enable damping (inertia) for the zoom as well?

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
```

Comment: Have you tested it ? It should be quicker than writing a question on SO :)

Comment: Of course I tested it. Seems not to work.

Comment: Yep, I mean the code does not implement it yet but it may come soon. You can check how `TrackballControls` do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added zoom damping to the `three.js r73` `OrbitControls`, **see this demo**:

Fiddle using three.js r107, but OrbitControls are still the r73 version:
http://jsfiddle.net/y62d4qnr/

Usage is just like the default Orbit Controls, you can play with these settings to customize it:

```
controls.constraint.smoothZoom = true;
controls.constraint.zoomDampingFactor = 0.2;
controls.constraint.smoothZoomSpeed = 5.0;
```

**Drawback**: works only for the mousewheel, not touch zoom or middle mouse. I guess it could be extended, but until now I did not care enough. Im open for suggestions.

My solution is based on this gist from paulkaplan dated 2013: https://gist.github.com/paulkaplan/5770247. Needless to say three.js and Orbit Controls changed a lot since then. I would be grateful if some former author would add this feature officially, but sometimes it takes quite a while ;-)

---

> To give you a quick overview I modified the following:

In `OrbitContraint()`:

Bunch of variables needed for zooming,

added function: `this.smoothZoomUpdate = function () { /* ... */ };`

and a call to it inside the `OrbitConstraint.update()` function:

```
this.update = function () {
    //...
    this.smoothZoomUpdate ();
    //...
}
```

Also inside the `THREE.OrbitControls()` modified the function `onMouseWheel() { /* ... */ }`

Comment: currently the zoom seems to be smoother. However, how do we make rotate and zoom happen simultaneously with this smooth effect?

Comment: Please explain further, I dont get your question. Smooth rotation is still avaliable, see: http://jsfiddle.net/rxh6obmp/

Comment: I agree. However, here in the fiddle we cannot zoom and rotate at the same time. There is a pause or a wait time, Is there any way we can make it possible?